type of solutions of $-u^{\prime\prime}=\lambda e^{u}$ based on the value of the parameter $\lambda$. (Gelfand problem).
My question comes from the book Stable Solutions of Elliptic Partial Differential Equations Louis Dupaigne, pages 30-31. \

Question: In the book, it defines $\lambda^{*}=\lambda^{*}(N)>0$ but dont give it any specific value and use it for the next statement: (Proposition 2.2.1 page 31 and Step 2 page 32). 
For some $\lambda^{*}>0$ there are exactly two solutions for $\lambda\in (0,\lambda^{*})$, one for $\lambda=\lambda^{*}$, and none $\lambda>\lambda^{*}$.
How to prove it for the case $N=1$? The general problem is this
\begin{equation}
 \begin{cases}
  -\Delta u=\lambda e^{u} \quad \text{in}\;\; B \\
   u=0   \quad \text{on}\;\; \partial B,
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda>0$ is a parameter and $B$ is the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^N$, $N\geq 1$. 
For $N=1$, the problem is
\begin{equation}
 -u^{\prime\prime}=\lambda e^{u}, \quad u(-1)=u(1)=0.
\end{equation}


Searching documentations where it is explained or proved i have found this academic paper Summary of “Gelfand–type problems involving the 1–Laplacian operator”
Assume that the domain is an interval $(a, b)$, in this case the equation is
$$
-\left(\frac{u^{\prime}}{\left|u^{\prime}\right|}\right)^{\prime}=\lambda e^u
$$
In this setting, we prove the following result.
Theorem 3.1. Set $\lambda^*=\frac{2}{b-a}$.

If $\lambda>\lambda^*$, problem has no solution
If $0<\lambda \leq \lambda^*$, the minimal solution is the trivial solution
If $0<\lambda<\lambda^*$, there exist non trivial solutions
If $\lambda=\lambda^*$, there exists only trivial solution


But the theorem isn't prove in the text. In my case b=-1 and a=1, but i want to know where i could see this proof. Exist other forms to demostrate it or others theorems that i can use in this problem?
